# Create Own Session in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to create my own session on magento so here is my code:

```
require 'app/Mage.php';

$value = "Hello World";
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyOwnSess($value);
```

But I'm having an error says:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php on line 462
```

**Additional:**
I'm trying to create a session on `config.php` which is located at `includes/config.php`

Can anyone help me... Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you need to initialize magento. the safest way to initialize it is by using initializer before your actual call to the model

```
Mage::init();
```

Or this should also solve your problem

```
Mage::app('default');
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a session on config.php which is located at includes/config.php

Comment: What is the reason to create session in config.php?? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: it's because I will having a `parameter`. This parameter can attached on any page on magento

`e.g http://mymagentowebsite/product/shoes?tracker=ABC123`

the parameter `tracker` can be attached on any in my magento.
Did you get it?

Comment: @Newbie **includes/config.php* is only parsed if compilation is enabled. You really, really, do not want to take this approach.

Comment: @Newbie why do you need session if the parameter is in the url. You should use observer at `controller_action_predispatch` event and check the request. If you need to save anything in session, you will have access to it in the observer as well.

Answer (score 1):

The key to getting the sessions in the different areas to work was the line

```
$core_session = Mage::getSingleton ( 'core/session', array ('name' => 'frontend' )
```

before the other ones were used.

so you should try like below

```
$core_session = Mage::getSingleton ( 'core/session', array ('name' => 'frontend' ) );

$url = Mage::getUrl ( '*/*/*', array ('_current' => true ) );

Mage::getSingleton ( 'core/session' )->setLastUrl ( $url );
```

above is just skeleton code. you can change it as per you need.

Comment: m trying to create a session on config.php which is located at includes/config.php